# Datastore Query Array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying run a Datastore query to get a list of names and prices. However, I keep getting this error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type '`Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreQueryResults`' to '`System.Collections.Generic.List<TestApp.Models.AllSportsStore>`'

This is the code I am using:

AllSportsStore.cs Page

```
public DatastoreDb _db;

[BindProperty]
public List<AllSportsStore> SportsStoreList { get; set; }


public void OnGet()
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "xxxxx.json"));
    _db = DatastoreDb.Create("projectid");
    Query query = new Query("Sports_db");
    IEnumerable<Entity> stores = _db.RunQuery(query).Entities;
    SportsStoreList = stores.Select(_ => new AllSportsStore
    {
        Name = _["Name"].ToString(),
        Price = _["Price"].ToString(),
    }).ToList();
}
```

AllSportsStore.cshtml page

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SportsStoreList.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SportsStoreList[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SportsStoreList[i].Price)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is the image of the datastore

[image: Datastore image]

Updated code result based on a comment
[image]

Comment: Because `DatastoreQueryResults` is not `List<AllSportsStore>`. But `DatastoreQueryResults` does contain a property `Entities` which is the collection of data

Comment: So what do I do to fix it? I am learning MVC

Comment: I has nothng to do with MVC. And I have no idea what your query returns - but if you use `foreach(var entity in results.Entities) {` you should be able to work it out

Comment: I get a null exemption

Comment: By the looks of it, you are trying to obtain a list of names and prices from Datastore, but to no avail. Just following up with @StephenMuecke's comments, could you please expand on the error you are getting when you try to follow his advice? Thank you.

Comment: yes that is what I am trying to do. When I run it, it says null exemption error and points to line 23 which is @foreach (var entity in results.Entities)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, you are trying to assign the wrong type to the `SportsStoreList` property.

Have a model to hold entity details from storage

```
public class SportsStoreItem {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Use the model in the *AllSportsStore.cs* Page

```
public class AllSportsStore : PageModel {

    private readonly DatastoreDb _db;

    public AllSportsStore() {
        _db = DatastoreDb.Create("projectid");
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<SportsStoreItem> SportsStoreList { get; set; }

    public IActionResult OnGet() {
        Query query = new Query("Sports_db");
        IEnumerable<Entity> stores = _db.RunQuery(query).Entities;
        SportsStoreList = stores.Select(_ => new SportsStoreItem {
            Name = (string)_["Name"],
            Price = (decimal)_["Price"]
        }).ToList();

        return Page();
    }
}
```

Note how the entities retrieved from the data store db were converted to strongly typed objects.

You should then be able to access the items in the list in the view/page.

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SportsStoreList.Count; i++) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SportsStoreList[i].Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SportsStoreList[i].Price)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: @DanNick debug the code. Use breakpoints. Check that the collection is populated after the query. Could be that the query is not returning the requested data.

Comment: looks like the query is not returning the data. That query example that I am using was taken from the data store docs on Google and as you can see the kind has data in it. ID, Name, and Prices are the only properties.

Comment: Also the data that you see in the image was entered through a form in the website. So I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Comment: I updated the information in my original post. I read the documentation incorrectly Query query = new Query("Sports_db") has to be the name of the kind. Once I changed that and a few other changes I was able to retrieve data. However, I uploaded a screenshot of the data. How do you fix this : { "stringValue": "Dan" } { "stringValue": "14.95" } so that it it looks like this: Dan 14.95

Comment: @DanNick Check update. I have to step away for a bit so leave a comment if you encounter any other issues.